# Water leaking though ceiling under bathroom

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leaks

When I run a bath or a shower I have a slow leak that comes through my ceiling from the 2nd floor down to the first floor.

The leak does not happen when the toilet is flushed.

The leak does not happen when the bathroom sink is used.

I filled the tub up with water and plugged the drain to confirm that the leak is not coming from the drain.  The leak only occurs when the bathtub shower or tub faucet is running.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: So check the shower.

Comment: Sounds like you've narrowed it down to the shower supply. There's not much more we can do from here. You'll need to get eyes on it.

Comment: Time to **A:** open the access panel if your house was built right. Or **B:** cut open the drywall to make an access panel if your house was built wrong, so that it will be built right when you are done fixing the leak.

Comment: Thank you all.  Just to confirm I should open up the drywall behind the shower where the tub faucet is?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. That would be most likely if the leak is related to running the water. You might check to see if you can isolate the leak to just the shower or just the tub faucet, but either way, you'll need access to the water pipes. Like @Ecnerwal mentioned, if you don't have an access panel, you might as well make one. You'll need it again one day.

Comment: Thank you.  The leak happens when I run the shower only.  The leak also occurs when I run only the bath.

Comment: As mentioned above the leak is probably in the wall on the supply side. However, sometimes it's hard to tell because of the time it takes to see the leak downstairs. I have found in most cases the leak is in the drain where it connects to the tub. Before you cut out an access panel pull the cover off the drain and check the integrity of the connection by pushing down on the bottom of the drain inside the drain itself. If there is any play in it that may be the problem.

Comment: Does the leak happen when the shower is running and the water only lands in the tub? If not it could be the sealant is bad around the tub edge, or you have bad grouting.

Comment: "*I filled the tub up with water and plugged the drain to confirm that the leak is not coming from the drain.*"  **This does not eliminate the drain because you have plugged the drain so water is not draining**. If  you fill the tub  and then turn off the water supply then drain the tub does it leak ? This will tell you if the drain is leaking.

Comment: I appreciate all the help here guys.  I decided to open the back of the wall and inspect the plumbing since I had no access door.  When I finally found the plumbing after cutting a few holes.  Lol.  The leak is coming from the handle that turns the water on/off and hot/cold.  I guess next step would be to shut the water off (can’t find valve) so I’ll shut off the water in the home, let the remaining water run through the tub faucet,  then remove this handle.  I’m not sure if the handle is broken or if whatever the handle is attached to is the culprit.  Any additional input would b appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close. Question was vague and OP has vanished. Not much value in it all.

Answer (score 1):

In your overflow cover, there is a foam like gasket, that keeps water from getting behind the wall when showering. Sometimes the gasket falls behind wall or just gets old. There are usually two screws that hold your overflow plate onto wall; unscrew them then you should see two more screws that hold the overflow and drainpipe close to wall and in place. Unscrew those two screws and see if possibly the black thick gasket is in place. It should be between the wall and pipe so when water goes down wall it has a good seal between the faceplate the wall and the drain pipe. If that gasket is ruined or damaged when you shower the water will go behind the wall and flow down into the bottom of your flooring and end up seeping through your ceiling. It's a very quick fix and most the time as they age the gaskets tend to degrade or even at times get pushed down at a place. I would check that first before you do anything else the easy fix. The gaskets are sold at any plumbing supply store, usually for about $2. A gasket is thin on the very top and thicker on the bottom. The thin part should go on the top and the thicker part should go on the bottom. It should fit right into your shower wall and pipe.